# how can i remove string and use the number in front of it

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a file like this.I use Ubuntu and terminal.

```
 1345345 dfgdfg
 1345 dfgdfg
 13445 dfgdfg
 1345345 ddfg
 15345 df
 145 dfgdfg
 45 dfgdfg
 15 dfgdfg
```

I want  to create a script that i can i remove the strings and divide the number  or multiply the number like this and print the result near by

```
 1345345 *3  or /3 result = 
 1345 *3 or /3
 13445 *3 or /3
 1345345 *3 or /3
 15345 *3  or /3
 145 *3 or /3
 45 *3  or /3
 15 *3  or /3
```

this is for a file with 50 or more entry's and then output it on a new text file 
All this i have made them on Ubuntu.
thanks

Comment: could you show us the code that you tried so far and isn't working?

Comment: You read the input file line by line and process each line by using a regex to extract the number and then printing the executed computation with that number.

Comment: i have create the scripts about exporting all this but i don't know how to remove the strings.What code should i show if i cannot create or think one ?

Comment: you can remove strings by using sed with regular expressions, like `cat input | sed -r 's/ *([0-9]+).*/\1/'`

Comment: why is it downvoted?If you don't understand let someone else to answer.

Answer (score 1):

a very basic example would be something like this:

```
cat input | sed -r 's/ *([0-9]+).*/\1/' | xargs perl -e 'for($c=0;$c<=$#ARGV;$c++) {print ($ARGV[$c] . ": " . $ARGV[$c] * 3 . "\n");}'
```

(input is a file that contains your data)

gives:

```
1345345: 4036035
1345: 4035
13445: 40335
1345345: 4036035
15345: 46035
145: 435
45: 135
15: 45
```

You'll need to flesh it out more to serve your complete purpose no doubt, but that's supposed to be part of the fun

So let's break it down.

1. we [pipe](http://www.ucblueash.edu/thomas/Intro_Unix_Text/IO_Redir_Pipes.html) (using `|`) the contents of our input file into a [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that only    extracts the first numbers and ignores everything else: `cat input | sed -r 's/ *([0-9]+).*/\1/'`

   - it takes any numbers that it can find after any or none spaces `*` (since the example had a few when I copied it)
   - with `([0-9]+)`
   - that may be followed by anything else `.*`
   - and replaces the complete string with its find that's what the `s/input/replace/` construct is about

   this would land you with the following result:

   `1345345
   1345
   13445
   1345345
   15345
   145
   45
   15`
2. you wish to perform an operation on this data: for this you need to use some programming language in general, like [python](http://python.org), [perl](http://perl.org), [ruby](http://ruby-lang.org) or whatever else suits your needs. (some things your shell will do just fine for you), I used perl here which begets us `| xargs perl -e 'for($c=0;$c<=$#ARGV;$c++) {print ($ARGV[$c] . ": " . $ARGV[$c] * 3 . "\n");}'`

   - So again we pipe the data to our next command with `|`
   - to send output from a previous pipe to another program as an argument we use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), it's as simple as just prepending your command with
   - next in your program you loop (`for($c=0;$c<=$#ARGV;$c++) { ... }` through the commandline arguments provided, perform your action (here we perform * 3) and print the result out (`print ($ARGV[$c] . ": " . $ARGV[$c] * 3 . "\n");`).
3. Once you have your data, [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) it to a new file, not yet done here

alternatively you could also use [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or many other programs, that's the beauty of *nix, it has many tools. The basic concept you're looking for however is [filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29) your data, working on it and spitting it out again.

Comment: Wow! `sed | perl` !  Why not simply use only perl?

Comment: why not use c then? It's mainly to show how to pipe and interact, it's not meant to be a complete nor a performant example. Depending on the specific person's prowess with programming chaining like this might actually be preferred or easier. It also allows you to create little building block programs to re-use later on. (the unix way)

Comment: Useless use of cat spotted! `cat file | sed '...'` that's terrible!

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) : (in this example, I'm not expecting a space between number and string)

```
perl -lne 's/\W//; print "$_ x 3 = ", $_ * 3' file.txt | tee newfile.txt
```

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{print $1 " x 3 = " $1 * 3}' file.txt | tee newfile.txt
```

Using only [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
 while read n x; do echo "$n x 3 = $((n * 3))"; done < file.txt | tee newfile.txt
```